# Cambiar a idiomas no internacionales ASPX

Tags: c#, aspx, idioma

Estoy programando en .net Framework una pagina .aspx y he conseguido cambiar el idioma en un dropdownlist al ingles y español, pero...¿como se añade un idioma como valenciano o gallego?
Los ficheros resx se llama Resource.EN.resx o Resource.ES.resx y los pilla perfectamente al instante.
¿cómo se hace con nuestros idiomas regionales? porque el Resource.VA.resx ya os digo que no me lo pilla XDDD
Gracias

Comment: Galleo y Valenciano no son idiomas sino dialectos. Así pues, no es ver qué código ISO de idioma tiene el gallego, sino mirar la [documentación](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/localization). Mira _Culture fallback scenarios_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La abreviación no siempre son las primeras 2 letras del idioma. Revisa si usando los códigos de [ISO 639-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) funciona. Gallego: GL, Valenciano: CA

Comment: Muchas gracias. No se donde estaba mirando la Iso pero no encontraba el idioma. Ya lo veo. Gracias :)